# How to properly index fields on a Rails join table migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4 introduced a feature for generating join table migrations:

```
bin/rails generate migration CreateTeamsUsersJoinTable team user
```

This results in the following file:

```
class CreateTeamsUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :teams, :users do |t|
      # t.index [:team_id, :user_id]
      # t.index [:user_id, :team_id]
    end
  end
end
```

You can see that the indices are commented out. Why is this? Am I supposed to make a decision about which one I want to use? Or are they implying that indices are optional? I want to make sure there is some sort of index on each field to avoid performance problems, but I'm not sure how to properly define the indices for these fields.

Answer (score 5):

To complete xlembouras answer, you make your choice based on how you query your table.

For example, if you have a view that shows the users of a given team, the query will look like this :

```
SELECT user.name FROM team_users tu 
INNER JOIN users u 
ON tu.user_id = u.id
WHERE tu.team_id = X
```

This benefits from `t.index [:team_id, :user_id]` but not `t.index [:user_id, :team_id]`

The database will only use one index seek on the first index to retrieve the user ids

If you have a view that shows the teams of a given user, the query would be something like the following :

```
SELECT team.name FROM team_users tu 
INNER JOIN team t 
ON tu.team_id = t.id
WHERE u.user_id = X
```

This benefits from `t.index [:user_id, :team_id]` but not `t.index [:team_id, :user_id]`

The database will only use one index seek on the first index to retrieve the team ids

That's because of the way composed index are stored :

[image: index tree]

Comment: Reading your good answer it occurs to me that a compund index (AKA composite, double index) does not make sense in simple join tables. Since the join tables are used to query data in one direction, as in your examples, we should have simple single-colum indices instead. We will never query for a particular user id AND team id, because that would only give us the association row, no additional data. Or am I mistaken...?

Answer (score 4):

I would have to say that the intention behind this is to let you choose the strategy that fits you better. That is usually a decision with two criteria

- how much overhead does indexing adds
- how you'll query your db

So they can not make that decision for you and add the indexing overhead as a convention.

In order to make that decision you need to know how you intend to query your database. In MySQL composite indexes can be of use for a set of queries.
[multiple-column index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

An index on `column_a, column_b, column_c` will be used for queries on

- all three fields together
- `column_a` alone
- `column_a` and `column_b` together

So there is a difference between

```
t.index [:team_id, :user_id]
```

and

```
t.index [:user_id, :team_id]
```

the actual full set of indexes that you 'll need is

```
t.index [:team_id, :user_id]
t.index :user_id
```

or

```
t.index [:user_id, :team_id]
t.index :team_id
```

In order to handle with an index all three cases.

#### example

if you find your app to use more frequently queries like

`user.teams` which translate to

`select * from teams where user_id = X`

an index on `user_id` (or `user_id, team_id`) can be handy

so `t.index [:user_id, :team_id]` should be your choice

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful, but I'm still having a hard time understanding. Can you elaborate a bit more on the differences between those examples? For example, is one combination better for `team.users` vs `user.teams`?

Comment: Also, let's say I'm using SQLite in development and PostgreSQL in production...is there a difference which indices should be used based on which are supported?

Comment: Please read http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys 
And btw, no difference beween SQLite and PostgreSQL.