# Why is the create join table from my migration different from the docs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, join

I want to create a ratings page like: https://nomadlist.com/amsterdam-netherlands

1. `rails g model Rating name user:references`
2. `rails g migration CreateJoinTableItemsRatings item rating`

I get:

`create_join_table :items, :ratings do |t|
  t.index [:item_id, :rating_id]
  t.index [:rating_id, :item_id]
end`

But from the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table) I see:

`create_join_table :items, :ratings do |t|
  t.index :item_id
  t.index :rating_id
end`

Why is there a difference? Which one is preferred and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator is the more performant (and preferred) migration.

There's a pretty detailed discussion here: [How to properly index fields on a Rails join table migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075782/how-to-properly-index-fields-on-a-rails-join-table-migration)

Comment: Great, I did not find that page. Will dig into it after my sleep.